# Eclipse "source not found" rt.jar

Tags: eclipse, plugins, java

I'm developing Eclipse plugin, but when I want to start debugging mode, it stops and shows this:

http://i47.tinypic.com/oicbbp.png

And I don't know what to do with it. Is there any solution?

**[EDIT]**

But if I start it normally (no debug mode), it starts without any warning or errors. It shows that error only in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `tr.jar` (what the title had) is very different to `rt.jar` because the `rt.jar` contains the core classes of the J2SE!  This is basically saying that Eclipse cannot find the source for the J2SE because it was not attached to the IDE.  If you start Eclipse in 'no debug' mode, the source becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to reach that class it couldn't find the source code of this "ResourceBoundle" class. You can search it and add it after that you can see the codes in eclipse.

Comment: But I'm not using ResourceBundle in my plugin.

Comment: It seems in calling hierarchy it is called in somewhere.